# Finite sum with falling factorial

Tags: co.combinatorics

I need to evaluate the following finite sum:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{h}(-1)^j\binom{h}{j}(jx)_{k},\qquad k\geq h,\, x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}
$$

and

$$
(jx)_{k}=jx(jx-1)\cdots(jx-k+1)
$$
is the falling factorial. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: @darijgrinberg There is $(jx)_k$ in the sum. In general this sum is not 0

Comment: @axl: Oh, I misread your $k\geq h$ as $h \geq k$; sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sum is $k!$ times the coefficient of $z^k$ in $[1-(1+z)^x]^h$. So it can be simplified for a few values of $x$ (specifically $x=0$, $1$, $-1$, $2$, or $1/2$) but not in general.